# T-SQL How can I query a column with incorrect JSON?

Tags: json, t-sql, ssms

I've been asked to create a VIEW off a table that includes a varchar(MAX) column containing a JSON string. Unfortunately, some of the entries contain double quotes that aren't escaped.

Example (invalid in Notes):

```
{"Eligible":"true","Reason":"","Notes":"Left message for employee to "call me"","EDate":"08/16/2021"}
```

I don't have access to correct wherever this is being inserted so I just have to work with the data as is.

So in my view I need to find a way to escape those double quotes.

I'm pulling the data like so:

```
JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.Notes') as Notes
```

However, I get the following error:

```
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 102.
```

I can't do a simple replace on the whole field because that would create invalid JSON also.

I tried JSON_MODIFY but run into the problem of getting the notes field to replace itself.

```
JSON_MODIFY(JsonData, '$.Notes', REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.Notes'), '"', '\"'))
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out how to handle this. Is there a way to escape those double quotes in my query?

Comment: When I run your code here on your example Json, I get `Left message for employee to ` as the output.  Can you please provide an example that returns the same error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

So this is incredibly hacky and there are probably several examples that could break it as is, but if you absolutely can't fix your source data output or simply flag bad JSON for manual adjustment, this may be the route you need to take and further flesh out.

Based on your example and a couple extras I have thrown in, with the help of a custom string splitting table valued function that maintains sort order, you can achieve the output as follows:

## Query

```
declare @t table (JsonData nvarchar(max));
insert into @t values('{"Eligible":true,"Reason":"","Notes":"Left message for employee to "call me"","EDate":"08/16/2021","Test":     "999","Another Test":"Value with " character"}');

with q as
(
    select t.JsonData
          ,s.rn
          ,case when right(trim(lag(s.item,1) over (order by s.rn)),1) in('{',':',',')
                then '"'
                else ''
                end    -- Do we need a starting double quote?
           + s.item    -- Value from the split text
           + case when right(trim(lead(s.item,1) over (order by s.rn)),1) not in('}',':',',')
                         and right(trim(s.item),1) not in('{','}',':',',')
                  then '\"'
                  else ''
                  end  -- Do we need an escaped double quote?
           + case when left(trim(lead(s.item,1) over (order by s.rn)),1) in('}',':',',')
                  then '"'
                  else ''
                  end  -- Do we need an ending double quote?
           as Quoted
    from @t as t
        cross apply dbo.fn_StringSplit4k(t.JsonData,'"',null) as s  -- By splitting on " characters, we know where they all are even though they are removed, so we can add them back in as required based on the remaining text
)
,j as
(
    select JsonData
          ,string_agg(Quoted,'') within group (order by rn) as JsonFixed
    from q
    group by JsonData
)
select json_value(JsonFixed, '$.Eligible') as Eligible
      ,json_value(JsonFixed, '$.Reason') as Reason
      ,json_value(JsonFixed, '$.Notes') as Notes
      ,json_value(JsonFixed, '$.EDate') as EDate
      ,json_value(JsonFixed, '$.Test') as Test
      ,json_value(JsonFixed, '$."Another Test"') as AnotherTest
from j;
```

---

## Output

| Eligible | Reason | Notes | EDate | Test | AnotherTest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| true |  | Left message for employee to "call me" | 08/16/2021 | 999 | Value with " character |

---

## String Splitter

```
create function [dbo].[fn_StringSplit4k]
(
     @str nvarchar(4000) = ' '              -- String to split.
    ,@delimiter as nvarchar(1) = ','        -- Delimiting value to split on.
    ,@num as int = null                     -- Which value to return.
)
returns table
as
return
                    -- Start tally table with 10 rows.
    with n(n)   as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)

                    -- Select the same number of rows as characters in @str as incremental row numbers.
                    -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest @str length.
        ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(isnull(@str,'')) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)

                    -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
        ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where substring(isnull(@str,''),t,1) = @delimiter)

                    -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
                    -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
        ,l(s,l) as (select s,isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter,isnull(@str,''),s),0)-s,4000) from s)
    
    select rn
          ,item
    from(select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
               ,substring(@str,s,l) as item
         from l
        ) a
    where rn = @num
       or @num is null;
```

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to avoid something like this, but I think you're right and it may be the only way. Thank you I will give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a stored procedure along these lines:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.clearJSon(@v nvarchar(max)) RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @i AS int
  DECLARE @security int
  SET @i=PATINDEX('%[^{:,]"[^,:}]%',@v)
  SET @security=0 -- just to prevent an endless loop
  WHILE @i>0 and @security<100
  BEGIN
    SET @v = LEFT(@v,@i)+''''+SUBSTRING(@v,@i+2,len(@v))
    SET @i=PATINDEX('%[^{:,]"[^,:}]%',@v)
    SET @security = @security+1
  END
  RETURN @v
END
```

which returns
`{"Eligible":"true","Reason":"","Notes":"Left message for employee to 'call me'","EDate":"08/16/2021"}` as the result of `dbo.clearJSon(JsonData)`

I have to admit though, that the above code would fail, if the unescaped quotes would be followed by one of ,:} or if it would trail one of {:,

Comment: That might be ok. I will give it a try! Thank you.